# pymetar.py metar weather library stopped working

Tags: python, weather

I was using Tobias Klausmann's pymetar.py to fetch airport weather metar reports.  It stopped working.
http://www.nws.noaa.gov/om/notification/scn16-16wngccb.htm  They shut the service down.
http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/
The Service http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/decoded/ was used on line 1047.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by changing line 1047 in pymetar.py to
http://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/observations/metar/decoded/ 
Hope that helps you!